# I'm trying to connect to a host that has SSL certificate I don't know where to set the hosts certificate in my request

Tags: php, laravel, ssl-certificate, soap-client

My project is laravel php and I'm calling the host through XML WSDLs SoapClient

Answer (score 0):

i think can do it in laravel from .htacess 
to redirect all route to https 
that you need?